# Knockout js, binding context and view model are very confusing

Tags: knockout.js

When I bind a view model with a view,

html

```
<div data-bind="text: $data.name"></div>
```

javascript

```
var viewModel = {
    name: ko.observable('Steve')
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The div shows the name Steve. The binding context contains the $data property, it binds the name in the viewModel where $data refers to with the div element. I understand that. But What I don't understand is that when I remove $data in the data-bind in the div tag, it still works. Without $data, doesn't the name refers to a property directly in the binding context called "name" which doesn't exist? what happens under the hood in the case when $data is not present?

Comment: The binding context is the viewModel object. $data also refers to the viewModel, hence why its possible to omit $data in your data-bind attribute.

Comment: @MaheshWarrier. Accroding to the doc, binding context is an object that contains special properties such as $data, $root, if binding context is viewModel, then it should contain these properties, which it does not.

Comment: Knockout adds those properties to your view model when you call applyBindings. If you really want to get into the nitty gritty, you can look into the source code: http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.4.0.debug.js. Specifically you'll want to look at the applyBindings function

Comment: @MaheshWarrier. If you are right, does that mean viewModel has a $data property that points to itself?

Comment: No, because ko created a _new_ object that extends your view model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works because knockout uses a `with` block. Your `text` binding's return value is wrapped inside:

```
"with($context){with($data||{}){return{" + bindingValue + "}}}";
```

As you can see [in the source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/bindingProvider.js#L68).

This piece of code means that your viewmodel properties will be searched first. If a property isn't present, knockout will check if it's in the binding context.

Here's an example how it sort of works:

```js
var vm = {
  vmProp: 'VMPROP'
};

var bindingCtx = {
  $ctxProp: 'CTXPROP',
  $data: vm
};

function log() {
  with(bindingCtx) {
    with($data) {
      console.log(vmProp);       // Works
      console.log($ctxProp);     // Also works
      console.log($data.vmProp); // Also works
    }
  }
}

log();
```

Comment: That's the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html). Your viewModel object in the current context will be applied to the body tag if 2nd parameter is not present to `ko.applyBindings`. It is because you not include 2nd parameter which is the `rootNode` for [applyBindings](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/bindingAttributeSyntax.js#L438). It causes to apply `$data` to `body` tag. So you can use your `viewModel` `properties` and `functions` anywhere inside your `body` tag.